# In Emacs Lisp, some of the keywords are not defined

Tags: emacs, lisp, keyword

I recently picked up an old book on lisp and I'm trying to learn lisp using emacs. I am using both the ielm mode and interactive-mode, but I ran into this problem of keywords not being define. I am following the book's example but sometimes I would get a

> *** eval error *** Symbol's function definition is void: -the keyword-

The keywords such as: DEFINE, TIMES, DIFFERENCES, ADD1, ect would not work. While other keywords such as: SQRT, MAX, MIN, ect would work.

I am a complete beginner in emacs so I don't quit understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

There are several [dialects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialect_%28computing%29) of lisp, e.g. Common Lisp, Scheme, Emacs Lisp, etc.
Functions, variables or keywords that are available in one dialect may not be in another one.

As Rainer said, the dialect from your book is probably not in use anymore and you shouldn't learn it. Pick a more recent one and buy a book or find documentation online. If you are new to Lisp, it is probably a good idea to start with [Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_%28programming_language%29) which is a major dialect of Lisp and it relatively simple.

Last thing: Emacs is an editor, you can use it to program in any Lisp dialect. Now, Emacs itself is (mainly) written in Emacs Lisp which is a Lisp dialect that was specially designed for Emacs. It is only useful to know it if you want to modify or  customize Emacs.

Comment: Is there a way to find out which dialect that I am using? And is there a way to add dialect to emacs? I am currently learning from this book:  http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0201084546/ref=olp_product_details?ie=UTF8&me=&seller=

Answer (score 1):

Your book is probably very old and uses a Lisp dialect which no longer is in use.

You may want to get a slightly newer version of that book.

See: http://people.csail.mit.edu/phw/Books/#AI  for old Common Lisp (from the 80s) code for the book.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably be better of with a book discussing `Emacs Lisp` (one is bundled with Emacs itself, type <kbd>C-h i m Emacs Intro RET</kbd> to access it).

Btw, this books looks ancient and I guess it describes a non-standard Lisp dialect. Consider reading something like [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/) or [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) instead.